# PHP add cookies in request post

Tags: php, cookies

Is it correct to add cookies obtained in this way in the $request?

```
$cookies = array();
foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
    parse_str($matches[1], $tmp);
    $cookies += $tmp;
  }
}

$request = array(
'http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header'=> "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
           "User-Agent:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6\r\n" .
           "Cookie: ".$cookies,
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I must add the content of the $cookies variable in the header field in "Cookie:". I simply did it:' "Cookie:". $cookies,' but I don't know if it is correct. Is $cookies an array? Is it not wrong to add it as an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set cookies in your webpage header, please use the [setcookie function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php)

And when accessing cookies, just use the `$_COOKIE` global variable which is an associative array.